# CDI bean constructor and @PostConstruct called multiple times

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi

After some experimentation, this appears to be an issue when using a CDI bean, and nothing to do with PrimeFaces which is what I originally assumed.

If I change the TableBeanLazy to be a Managed Bean using @ManagedBean, then the constructor and @PostConstruct method only get called once, as I was expecting.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

===================================================

I'm quite new to JSF and PrimeFaces, so any guidance will be greatly appreciated.  I've searched for other postings, and read a number of similar ones, but can't find a solution.

I am trying to get the Lazy Loading Data Table example on the PrimeFaces Showcase site working in my project, but I'm having problems due to the bean class not behaving as I was expecting.

I've made a few changes to the sample code from the PrimeFaces site:- renamed TableBean class to TableBeanLazy; added annotations to the class; allocated static String arrays; moved initialisation from the constructor to the @PostConstruct initialise() method; allocated the *cars* member variable.

I've also added trace messages to the constructor and the @PostConstruct method which show that both are being called multiple times when the table is first displayed, multiple times with each click of a search icon, and multiple times with each character entry in a filter field.

This results in the random list of Car objects being recreated each time an action is taken, so sort and filter will never produce the expected results - which they do when running the example directly on the PrimeFaces Showcase site.

Although I was originally using @ViewScoped, I have also tried @RequestScoped and finally @SessionScoped, but all behave in the same way.

Is multiple calls to the constructor and @PostConstruct the expected behaviour for a bean?

If so, how can the sample code given on the PrimeFaces Showcase site possibly work?

How do I resolve this?

**Environment**

```
PrimeFaces 3.5
JSF 2.1
JDK 1.7
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206)
Netbeans IDE 7.3
Windows 7 Pro x64
```

**MyTable.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  template="./resources/templates/platform_tpl.xhtml"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

  <ui:define name="body">
    <h2 style="margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">Cars List</h2>

    <h:form id="form">
      <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBeanLazy.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"
        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" selection="#{tableBeanLazy.selectedCar}" id="carTable" lazy="true">

      <p:column headerText="Model" sortBy="#{car.model}" filterBy="#{car.model}">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Year" sortBy="#{car.year}" filterBy="#{car.year}">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" sortBy="#{car.manufacturer}" filterBy="#{car.manufacturer}">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Color" sortBy="#{car.color}" filterBy="#{car.color}">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
      </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
    </h:form> 
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**TableBeanLazy.java**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package BackEnd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;  
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;  

@Named(value = "tableBeanLazy")
@SessionScoped
public class TableBeanLazy
{
  static String[] colors = new String[10];
  static String[] manufacturers = new String[10];
  static String[] models = new String[5];

  private LazyDataModel<Car> lazyModel;  

  private Car selectedCar;  

  private List<Car> cars;  

  static
  {
    colors[0] = "Black";  
    colors[1] = "White";  
    colors[2] = "Green";  
    colors[3] = "Red";  
    colors[4] = "Blue";  
    colors[5] = "Orange";  
    colors[6] = "Silver";  
    colors[7] = "Yellow";  
    colors[8] = "Brown";  
    colors[9] = "Maroon";  

    manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";  
    manufacturers[1] = "BMW";  
    manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";  
    manufacturers[3] = "Audi";  
    manufacturers[4] = "Renault";  
    manufacturers[5] = "Opel";  
    manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";  
    manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";  
    manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";  
    manufacturers[9] = "Ford";

    models[0] = "Sports";
    models[1] = "Saloon";
    models[2] = "SUV";
    models[3] = "Hybrid";
    models[4] = "Estate";
  }  

  public TableBeanLazy()
  {
    System.out.println("-->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy");
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void initialise()
  {
    System.out.println("-->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy");

    cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    populateRandomCars(cars, 5);

    lazyModel = new LazyCarDataModel(cars);  
  }

  public Car getSelectedCar()
  {
    return selectedCar;
  }  

  public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar)
  {
    this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
  }

  public LazyDataModel<Car> getLazyModel()
  {
    return lazyModel;
  }

  private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size)
  {
    System.out.println("-->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
      list.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor()));  
    }  
  }  

  private String getRandomColor()
  {
    return colors[(int)(Math.random() * 10)];
  }

  private String getRandomManufacturer()
  {
    return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
  }

  private String getRandomModel()
  {
    return models[(int)(Math.random() * 5)];
  }

  private int getRandomYear()
  {
    return (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
  }
}
```

**Output on initial display of table**

```
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
```

**Output when search icon clicked**

```
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.setRowIndex(LazyDataModel.java:62)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:409)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:401)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:289)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:261)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:227)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
  at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:639)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
  at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
  at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.setRowIndex(LazyDataModel.java:62)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:409)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:401)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:289)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:261)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:241)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:508)
  at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:639)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
  at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1170)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
  at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.setRowIndex(LazyDataModel.java:62)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:409)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:401)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:289)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:261)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processUpdates(UIData.java:253)
  at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processUpdates(DataTable.java:550)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:510)
  at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
  at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:639)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
  at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1229)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
  at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In constructor for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In initialise for TableBeanLazy
INFO: -->  In populateRandomCars for TableBeanLazy
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's your first piece of advice with CDI and JSF - **Never mix CDI with JSF annotations.**

Your problem is that you use `@javax.inject.Named` a CDI annotation with `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` - a JSF annotation.

In CDI you would do:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "tableBeanLazy")
@SessionScoped
public class TableBeanLazy {...}
```

Note that the above will work perfectly fine with JSF.

In a pure JSF way you would do:

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(value = "tableBeanLazy")
@SessionScoped
public class TableBeanLazy {...}
```

I would recommend sticking with CDI all the way. However, CDI currently does not provide an alternative for the JSF `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` out of the box. To get it in CDI look into Apache Deltaspike.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to understand the problem and to provide a solution that works.  One odd thing though.  When following your advice, the TableBeanLazy constructor gets called twice, but @PostConstruct initialise() is only called once.

Comment: For CDI that has to do with how CDI is implemented, i.e. proxies. See this http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/WhyIsTheConstructorInvokedTwiceWhenANormalScopedBeanIsCreated .

Comment: To go a bit further, the constructor gets invoked only once per proxy creation and once per bean creation. This means, in the case of @ViewScoped beans for example, that the first access to the bean after the application starts the bean's constructor will be invoked twice. On subsequent creations (of the same bean type) the constructor will only be invoked once.

Comment: Same goes for @RequestScoped. Basically, the constructor will be invoke x + 1 times, where x is the number of beans created.

Comment: The link by @rdcrng was broken. This one is correct: http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/WhyIsTheConstructorInvokedTwiceWhenANormalScopedBeanIsCreated.html

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more why is it preferred the use of `@ManagedBean` over `@Named` in this situation, because I have read that it is generally more encouraged the use of `@Named`, if posible when/how to use each?

Comment: also, is it possible to achieve this using only the more widely accepted `@Named` bean? (considering that you want to use this same beanfor CDI and management of views<facelets>)

Comment: @ordiel If you think I'm saying '@ManagedBean' is preferred, you read my answer wrong. CDI is always preferred if the environment supports it. In any case, don't mix CDI and JSF managed beans.